# Javascript nested JSON merge specific object name value as string

Tags: javascript, json

Using vanilla Javascript, I would like to return the city name of multiple location as a String in the nested JSON example below.
Using push doesn't work because of the complexity of the JSON structure (I can't change) which result in a separate loop.

```
"locations":[
    {
      "location":{
          "city":"New place 1",
          "other":"random"
      }
    },
    {
      "location":{
          "city":"New place 2",
          "other":"random dom"
      }
    }
]
```

Expected output:
"New place 1", "New place 2"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 0):

Or, more easy solution.

```js
let locations = [
    {
      "location":{
          "city":"New place 1",
          "other":"random"
      }
    },
    {
      "location":{
          "city":"New place 2",
          "other":"random dom"
      }
    }
];

let Array = [];
locations.forEach(function(par){
  Array.push(par.location.city);
})

let str = "";
Array.forEach(function(par){
  str += par +", ";
});

str = str.slice(0,-2);
  

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to build your string. Here I have also used `.slice` to remove the trailing comma and space at the end of your string:

```js
const locs = {locations:[{location:{city:"New place 1",other:"random"}},{location:{city:"New place 2",other:"random dom"}}]},

res = locs.locations.reduce((acc, loc) => `${acc}${loc.location.city}, `, ``).slice(0,-2);
console.log(res);
```

If you just want an array as your output you can use `.map`:

```js
 const locs = {locations:[{location:{city:"New place 1",other:"random"}},{location:{city:"New place 2",other:"random dom"}}]},
 
arr = locs.locations.map(loc => loc.location.city);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
let locations = [
    {
      "location":{
          "city":"New place 1",
          "other":"random"
      }
    },
    {
      "location":{
          "city":"New place 2",
          "other":"random dom"
      }
    }
];

const result = locations.map(loc => loc.location.city);

console.log(result);
console.log(result.join(','));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
let locations = [{"location":{"city":"New place 1","other":"random"}},{"location":{"city":"New place 2","other":"random dom"}}];

let result = locations.map(v => '"' + v.location.city + '"').join(", ");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const locs = [
    {
      "location":{
          "city":"New place 1",
          "other":"random"
      }
    },
    {
      "location":{
          "city":"New place 2",
          "other":"random dom"
      }
    }
]

const res = locs.map(d => d.location.city).join(', ');
console.log(res); // "New place 1, New place 2"
```

Nice and simple with `locs.map(d => d.location.city).join(', ')`

Answer (score 0):

One liner Using `map` and `String constructor`

```js
var a = {
  locations: [{
    location: {
      city: "New place 1",
      other: "random"
    }
  }, {
    location: {
      city: "New place 2",
      other: "random dom"
    }
  }]
}
console.log(String(a.locations.map(e => e.location.city)))
```